# Inserting an array into a mysql database column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I am trying to insert values from a multi select drop down in a form to a mysql db column. For example: The drop down would have one or more choices chosen then when the form is posted it would insert the data into one column in a mysql db. I'm stuck at how to insert the data.

Comment: Consider normalizing your data. Make your table "long and skinny" instead of "variable width array" forced into a single field

Comment: Before you head down this path - arrays to string to column - consider whether you'll ever want to query that data using SQL.  If yes, then you need to start normalizing now, as mlt suggests.

Comment: Could you be a little more precise in your question? What is your code so far? How is the rest of your app (or your exercise)?

Comment: Some people will tell you to serialize/normalize/jsonize/other-ize, but I would advise not to follow such advice. This is just plain bad practice and makes it totally pointless to use a RDB system. Try instead to learn how it works from actual coding examples from sources you know are trustworthy.

Comment: @Jivan - can you explain a little more why normalizing a database is bad practice?

Comment: @andrewsi oops. Did I say 'normalizing'? My mistake, I really meant serializing (which is not the same indeed). Normalizing is of course the way to go. But IMHO serializing data in a DB field has more drawbacks than it has benefits.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to insert in single row then you can use implode() to generate comma separated data, or you can do json_encode() and add to your colum.

Say you get the data as

```
$data = array("one", "two", "tree");

// output one, two, three
$insert_data = implode(",", $data);


or  

$insert_data = json_encode($data);
```

Thats for inserting data in single column. While retrieving you can do explode() or json_decode() to get the return data and can use them in the multi-select again.

If you want one row for each item then just loop through the array and add them

Comment: Mr. downvoter have some guts to write the reason while do the downvote.

Comment: bad db structure, normilise

Comment: And trust me I designed the database for the OP.

Comment: you did? why did you set it up this way ?

Comment: What about serialize php array? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php Create string, insert in mysql. When get back from mysql, unserialize the array. What problems may be?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to think about:

If there is a one to many relationship - it shouldn't be in one column, look into multiple tables and changing your database structure.

If you really want to pass in an array you will need to convert it to string using the php built in function `implode`, then using the built in function `explode` to retrieve the column from the db

```
$arr = array('val1','val2');
$string = implode(',',$arr);

//Do db insert

//Do db retrieve

$arr = explode(',',$string);
```

http://php.net/function.implode

Answer (score 1):

you can turn the array into a single string with https://www.php.net/function.implode

```
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
```

Comment: to the ones downvoting everything, you might leave an explanation as to why.  otherwise toss off somewhere else.  I upvoted everyone to counteract you.

Answer (score 1):

set the type of the column to string, then use the function serialize($array) to convert the array into a string. When you want to get the string back to an array, use unserialize($string)