# Saving Array CakePhp

Tags: arrays, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I wanna save values from an array into one field of my database. I've been using that code but nothing got saved.

```
$this->Form->input('Model.0.field1');
$this->Form->input('Model.0.field2');
$this->Form->input('Model.1.field1');
$this->Form->input('Model.1.field2');
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the save code you've tried to use? Which version of CakePHP are you using (it makes a big difference). The official documentation goes into great detail on how to save so make sure you've properly read through it!

Comment: Hey! Yeah I've read about it and followed every step but nothing got saved :/ ! I'm using CakePhp 2.6.0 . I have an HABTM association , and my save code is in the association controller.

Comment: Please add the code you're using in your controller to save with to the question. The form inputs don't really provide enough information about what you're trying or what is going wrong.

Comment: If you really want to store this array into one database field you can `json_encode($this->request->data['Model'])` and then you can easily `json_decode($value, true);` it back when you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to save data with `json_encode()` value.

```
// In your controller

public function test() {

    if($this->request->is('post'))   {

        //If you want to insert in single row then you can use json_encode() and add to your colum.

        $insert_data = json_encode($this->request->data);

        $data = array(); 
        // Load your model where you want save data

        $this->loadModel('Test'); 
        // set attribute name where you want to save

        $data['Test']['value'] = $insert_data; 
        $this->Test->save($data);

        //For viewing your data
        $fetchedData = $this->Test->find('all');
        foreach($fetchedData as $items) {
            var_dump(json_decode($items['Test']['value']));
        }
    }   
}
```

> You can use implode() to generate comma separated data. If you want to use `implode()`, look at [Inserting an array into a mysql database column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389299/inserting-an-array-into-a-mysql-database-column)